# Can I open up a simple file browser in a django admin action?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm a little new to customizing the django admin and maybe what I want is a little advanced but I was wondering if I can launch a file browser in my custom action.  Just something simple that will return a list of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite what I originally had in my head but there's a blog post for a pretty simple file loader solution which shows even the changes needed for the template.
https://blog.rousek.name/2017/08/11/uploading-multiple-files-in-django-admin/